# Is this a bug in .net DateTime.Compare function?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a form with two DateTimePicker controls

DateTime.Compare should return 0 if they have the same value, but it thinks they are not the same:

```
?DateTime.Compare(DatePicker.dtpFrom.Value, DatePicker.dtpTo.Value)
1

?datepicker.dtpFrom.Value
#9/20/2012 7:00:46 PM#

?DatePicker.dtpTo.Value
#9/20/2012 7:00:46 PM#
```

Am I somehow not thinking clearly? Surely this isn't some bug in the .NET Framework.

**UPDATE**
OK I checked the millisecond values and they are off (very slightly). Quirky! I guess it has to do with some subtle delay when the controls are constructed and their default values are set.

```
?DatePicker.dtpTo.value.ToString("fff")
"616"
?datepicker.dtpFrom.Value.ToString("fff")
"619"
```

I only care about the date portion, so I solved it:

```
If DateTime.Compare(DatePicker.dtpFrom.Value.Date, DatePicker.dtpTo.Value.Date) > 0 Then
                MsgBox("From_Date cannot be after To_Date", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Data validation error")
```

Comment: I agree with Matt.  > 0 is not a test for equality.   And if you are going to answer your own question the proper format is to post the answer as an answer.

Comment: **>I agree with Matt. > 0 is not a test for equality**. Yes I'm not testing for equality. FromDate must be equality to or greater than ToDate. But the result of comparing two DateTimePicker control's unedited default values is that they are not equal and I expected they would be.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Blam seems to think it works best in the question. but after reading this, ok, i'll post it! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: What,  "And if you are going to answer your own question the proper format is to post the answer as an answer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when comparing multiple DateTimePicker controls. Small differences in the millisecond portion of their values can cause unexpected comparison results, even when no user has edited their default values.

For example, say you have two DateTimePicker controls on your form: FromDate and ToDate, used to establish a date range for a report.

As the question above shows, comparing the two values to ensure that the FromDate is not greater than the ToDate, can result in unexpected results.

If you only care about the Date portion of these controls, you can drop the time value when doing the comparison by reading the Date property on the Value property.

```
If DateTime.Compare(dtpFrom.Value.Date), DateValue(dtpTo.Value.Date) > 0 Then
{invalid range error message}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to check the [.Net documentation on DateTime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx), a value of 1 implies that dtpFrom.Value is greater than dtpTo.

I'd also suggest there's a millisecond or two difference between the dates, since even down to the second they're likely not to be the same.

I'd suggest comparing the .ToString("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss") values to get around millisecond differences

**UPDATE**

Further to the comments, here's a better suggestion for stripping off the milliseconds

`dateTime.AddTicks( - (dateTime.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth OK so string is not a good way to compare date portion.  But Matt is correct on > 0 is not an equality comparison.

Comment: in my app i'm just testing that FromDate is less than or equal to ToDate, otherwise I complain to the user. (updated question again to make this more clear). What threw me off was that the unedited, default value of two datetimepicker controls on the same form are not the same value. I expected they would be!